# Using Google Sheets, how do I increment a row value as I drag down while still referencing the same columns in a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently using this formula to calculate the average of specific columns in another sheet:

AVERAGE(indirect("'Sheet 1'!B2:M2"))

A new column is added weekly so I used that formula to keep referencing the same columns vs it becoming C2:N2.

I have to reference many rows and would like the formula to be able to adjust to reference the different row values when I drag it down. What do I need to change for that to happen?

Comment: I don't understand why you have `indirect` in your formula. Do you not get the same result with `AVERAGE('Sheet 1'!B2:M2)`. And you can drag this down as many rows as you wish.

Comment: A new 'B' column is inserted every week and when I just used AVERAGE it automatically changed the formula to C2:N2 when it was added. I always want to be referencing B2:M2 no matter if a new column has been inserted or not. I'm sure there is another way to do that but I just haven't figured it out yet.